# Map showing only grid not a map in ios simulator for alloy titanium application

Tags: ios, titanium, maps, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I created a simple application to view map in iOS simulator using alloy application..I can see the map it's just showing only the grid...

I even downloaded sample application "geocoder" provided by appcelerator.Even for that map is not showing..

Also my internet connection is working fine..

Do we need to enable something like internet settings ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For android emulator just add inbuilt 'ti.map' module in tiapp.xml to show normalMapview ..but for iOS simulator u need to write seperate API & Download,add 
 GoogleMapsv1 Module in to ur workspace & add it in tiapp.xml then it will work..
:=)

(note: adding 'ti.map' wont work in IOS simulator :( )